# where clause returns nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a very simple query:

```
select br.BranchCode, br.BranchName,cn.Country, cd.AggregateCreditExposure as [CreditExposure] 
from Branches br join CreditDetails cd 
on br.BranchCode = cd.BranchCode join Country cn    
on br.CountryCode = cn.CountryCode
```

and it gives me the result set:

[image]

When I try to put `where` clause, it returns no result:

```
select br.BranchCode, br.BranchName,cn.Country, cd.AggregateCreditExposure as [CreditExposure] 
from Branches br join CreditDetails cd 
on br.BranchCode = cd.BranchCode join Country cn    
on br.CountryCode = cn.CountryCode
where cn.Country = 'France'
```

Expected Result:

[image]

Strangely it returns nothing. Why doesn't it work??

Schema of `Country`: (providing only related table)

- CountryCode int PK
- Country varchar(50)

Comment: Maybe you've got blank space or other invisible characters in your data.

Comment: What happens when you use `where cn.Country LIKE 'France%'` ?

Comment: @TabAlleman No, I've tried many countries. I am sure there's no typing mistake

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables let me check

Comment: I'd try it LIKE '%France%' too, just to be sure.

Comment: @Tab Alleman. Yes you were right. There was a space after every Country in the database. Post it as answer and i'll accept it

Comment: @Shaharyar - did you, or the person who entered the data, by chance copy the countries from Excel?  I've seen that happen more than once.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables yes I did :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've either got whitespace or some invisible characters in your data.

The way I always test for this in SSMS is to take the result of your first query, that does return data, click on the box in the grid that contains "France" (in this instance) go up to the query editor and paste (ctrl-v) in between two characters like ''.   If there's some white space, you'll see something like this:

```
'France   '
```

instead of this:

```
'France'
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is you have a newline '\n' at the start of "France" which doesn't actually show up in "Select * from " > Try and use LIKE 'France', if that works, it has to be a newline character.

try

```
= '\nFrance'
```

or

```
= '\nFrance\n'
```

PS: i know this because i had this similar issue sometime back.